# Can I ask a question which is an amalgam of several different questions?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, too-broad

When I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156583/how-to-move-an-object-along-curved-path-on-scroll-using-angular-4-javascript) on Stack Overflow I received multiple downvotes. In the comments one user specified that:

> This is not an appropriate "question" for stack overflow as its
>   actually an amalgam of several different questions: how do I attach a
>   scroll event handler on the window? How do I move image on the screen
>   using JavaScript/CSS? How do I animate an image? How do I move
>   something along a bezier curve using JavaScript? etc.

Comment: Why are you asking a question that you already know the answer to?

Comment: I cannot find it mentioned in the policy.

Comment: Such a question is going to be Too Broad, as you can see from the fact that your question has been attracting Too Broad close votes.

Comment: *I cannot find it mentioned in the policy* – Yes, and it needs to be fixed: [Explicitly disadvise multiple questions per question in help/dont-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300453/255554)

Comment: I disagree that this is specific to Stack Overflow. Both the proscription against asking multiple questions at once and the absence of a written rule to that effect (other than the explanation of Too Broad) are network-wide phenomena.

Comment: also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch http://idownvotedbecau.se/noeffort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but not as a single post. This is probably the #1 beginner mistake. They seem to feel they can only have one question at a time, so they ask the entirety of their problem in a single post. As you can see, such questions get closed as Too Broad. Another possibility is "I need to choose between A and B, which is best?" which gets closed as Opinion Based.

The solution is to ask a bunch of questions, each in their own separate post. Possibly all at once, or possibly as you move through your decision process. Once all the questions are answered, your code will work or you will have the solution to your problem, or you will be able to make your decision. It's more work, obviously: you have to break the programming problem up into smaller pieces and use the right words for things you may not even know about yet. You have to work out what goes into "best" for you (cost, speed, weight, opening hours, etc. depending on what you're asking about) and then ask specifically about those aspects of the things you're considering. The benefit is: you get answers. And that's why you're here.

Comment: I don't understand the first two sentences of your second paragraph. It is either my language comprehension or something is off. I now read it as that you do need to ask a bunch of questions in a single post, which contradicts your very first sentence. I'm confused.

Comment: Several posts. Each with one question. It is ok to add several posts at once as long as each is a separate and distinct question.