# Will splitting my question be more likely to generate answers?

Tags: discussion, multiple-questions

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825663/cannot-get-exceed-datagrid-styles-not-giving-what-i-want) I have listed a few styling changes I'd like some help with. I haven't got any answers, but one user has commented that asking each question separately might provoke some answers.

I put these (sub)questions all together because they are all of a piece, namely, styling a grid. My thought was that anyone who could respond to any one point would likely be able to respond to most, if not all. Also, if each was a separate question, some might not be seen.

But since I have no replies at all, maybe I should to this. However, I'd like to get some feedback before proceeding.

Comment: I just realized that there is a meta for Stackoverflow itself and did not know this site was for Stackexchange.  In that light, it certainly is off-topic.  Is it possible to move my OP to the Stackoverflow meta page?  If so, I would appreciate it if one of the people who put this on hold would just move it there.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at this from the perspective of future visitors looking for an answer to a specific question.

It's true that someone with knowledge of one question will likely have some knowledge of the other questions, but for people in the future visiting the site (which is the real goal), the extra questions may just convolute the question and take away from what they're looking for.

Also, the reasons you're likely to get more responses from a more narrow question are:

- There's less of a risk of the question being poorly recieved for being too broad. People may decide that your question isn't worth their time if they aren't "rewarded" as much for answering it.
- Broad questions often become "chameleon questions", where the OP asks endless other questions instead of just realizing (or caring) that their question has already been answered. It becomes a chore maintaining an answer on such a question, so I personally avoid questions where it's apparent the OP may never be satisfied.
- Broader questions require more effort. If someone's asking 4 questions and you answer 1 of them, there's always a chance you'll get "but what about x, y, and z" comments. To answer the "whole question" is much more of an effort because you're needing to cover a broader expanse of knowledge.

So yes, split your questions! If they're good questions, you'll get more rep, potentially badges, and you'll be contributing more to the community.

Of course though, make sure each "sub question" really is a good, well researched question. Spamming the site with questions that have already been asked a thousand times over just wastes people's time.

Answer (score 1):

I am a great believer in focused Q&A and for that there should be only [one question asked per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300459/215590).

The answer to your first question may well enable you to know the answer to some or all of the subsequent questions.

If not, then just ask another question separately.

Linking to earlier questions to provide some background is a way to reduce how much repeat content needs to go into each question that you ask and to help tie your questions together.

It is fine to ask multiple questions separately at the same time, but sometimes it may make sense to ask one or two and hold the others, in case answers to it/them mean the others do not need to be asked.